# Methods overloading doesn't work on Typecsript

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling with function overloading on Typescript, maybe someone will be able to explain more deeply how it works.

So, the task is simple as that:
I've a class **Point** with **x, y: number** variables on it.

I need to create the function distance with three implementations, the implementations are:

```
- no args: distance from this point to (0, 0);
- `distance(other: Point)` - distance from this point to a given instance of
    `Point`;
- `distance(x, y)` - distance from this point to a given point (x, y).
```

My code is:

```
  distance(): number;
  **distance**(other?: Point): number;
  distance(x?: number, y?: number) {
      return 42;
  }
```

The linter is keeping to yell at me with this:

[image: VS yell]

How can I achieve the desired result to satisfy the condition?

I know how it could be done if I had primitive types, but I'm struggling with this specific "Point" type on the second implementation.

If I'll write something like `other?: Point | {x?: number, y?: number}` it doesn't work either.

Would be glad to get any info or useful link resource about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way these are written in Typescript are basically:

```
signature1()
signature2()
implementationThatCombinesAllPreceding();
```

So if we want to rewrite your function, it would have to (probably) look something like this:

```js
  distance(): number;
  distance(other: Point): number;
  distance(x: number, y: number);
  distance(arg1?: Point|number, arg2?: number) {
      return 42;
  }
```

The 4th 'implementation' signature does not show up in users' autocomplete system, so you don't have to worry about it being 'ugly'.

But it is the combination of all 3 earlier signatures. Inside the function body you will have to figure out based on the argument types which form was called.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. 

Thank you a lot @Evert 
I would not have guessed this by myself for sure. 

Thanks again for your answer and wish you a great day!